# Traefik docker DNS challenge with Namecheap not working

Tags: docker, dns, traefik

Traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.auth.forward]
  address = "http://forward-oauth:4181"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
[docker]
endpoint="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain="docker.localhost"
watch=true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "tim@tim.com"
storage = "acme.json"
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "namecheap"
delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.tim.com"
  sans = ["timelfelt.com"]

[file]

[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
       url = "http://192.168.192.116"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
      backend = "backend1"
      passHostHeader = true
      [frontends.frontend1.routes.adfs]
          rule = "Host:adfs.blah.com"
```

I get an error message in the Traefik docker log:

time="2018-11-10T06:29:28Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*.tim.com,tim.com\" : unable to generate a wildcard certificate in ACME provider for domain \"*.tim.com,tim.com\" : ACME needs a DNSChallenge"

Both the namecheap API and username are set on the host. 80 and 443 are available as well.

Answer (score -1):

The error `ACME needs a DNSChallenge` comes when the DNS challenge configuration is not defined.

The ACME configuration is a part of the static configuration, so you need to stop and restart Traefik when you change this section.

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7basics/#configuration